# Python Dictionary Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to sort it according to its key. Although I dont have an error, my key value (date) is not sorted.

If anyone could help me, I will be happy.
Thanks.

```
    d = defaultdict(list)

    for row in rows:
        date = row[0]
        speed = float(row[1])

        if date not in d:
            d[date] = [speed]
        elif date in d:
            speeds = d[date]
            speeds.append(speed)
            d[date] = speeds

        date = d.keys()
        date = sorted(d,key=lambda key:d[key])

        print date
```

"Print date" result:

```
['2015/01/01 10:04', '2015/01/01 08:40', '2015/01/01 10:14', '2015/01/01 09:56', '2015/01/01 09:54', '2015/01/01 10:08', '2015/01/01 10:06', '2015/01/01 10:10', '2015/01/01 10:16', '2015/01/01 09:52']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: No, I have used all these recommended algorithm but I have a non sorted result at the end. @minitoto

Comment: Regular python dictionaries have no order in python. use ordered dictionary. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe changing

```
date = d.keys()
```

to

```
date = sorted( d.keys() )
```

and removing

```
date = sorted(d,key=lambda key:d[key])
```

should work? I think the above line sorts by the contents in d[key] and not by key. If not, sorting by datetime objects should work as well:

```
import datetime
dates = sorted( [datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") for i in d.keys()] )

# to access dictionary values in order:
for date in dates:
    entry = d[ date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") ]
```